# How to iterate over multiple sheets and insert new columns in multiple workbooks in python

Tags: python, excel, loops

I am trying to  iterate over multiple sheets and insert new columns in multiple workbooks in python, here is my code:

file_list is the list of all workbooks that each have multiple sheets , and I am trying to insert new columns in each sheet of every workbook.
when I run the code, it gives me this error: "ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>"
The error occurs in the second loop for sheets.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
  for i, file in enumerate(file_list):
   print(i, file)
   wb = pd.ExcelFile(file)

  print(wb.sheet_names)
sheets = pd.read_excel(workbook, None)

   for sheet in wb.sheet:
        
        file1 = pd.read_excel(file_list[i], sheet)
        file1.insert(loc=2, column ='group_number', value = (file1.groupby(['p_key']).ngroup() + 1000) + group_number)
        file1.insert(loc=3, column ='batch_number', value = file1['group_number'].apply(lambda x: round_down(x, 1000)))
        file1.insert(loc=8, column = "primary_owner_2", value = file1["primary_owner"])
        wb.save("batched_"+ file_list[i][6:])
       # file1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet, index = False)
        group_number = group_number + len(file1.groupby(by = "p_key"))

   print(group_number)
```

I am expecting the second loop of the code works but it doesnt.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your error. Please tidy up the indentation of the code and state which error the line is occurring on.

Comment: The error occurs at "file1.to_excel(writer + file_list[i][6:]+ sheet_name = str(sheet), index = False)
                  ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression